# Is there a compiler switch to turn off support for Generics in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-micro-framework

I am working with a partner where we are trying to move a complex driver from the .NET platform to the .NET MicroFramework.

The problem is that the .NET MF doesnt support Generics and when we try to build the application the last "link" operation exits with the error code "CLR_E_PARSER_UNSUPPORTED_GENERICS".
There is however no information on WHERE (module, code-line).

As far as we know nobody has intentionally inserted Generics and they have been really looking over the code to identify what the problem is with no luck.

So my question is: Is there some way to turn off support for Generics in VS2010 so that the compiler will flag the offending line ?

Comment: You can decompile with reflector. It could be some language constructs implicitly use generics, like anonymous types. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/12/20/why-are-anonymous-types-generic.aspx

Comment: Here's a very naïve basic suggestion (so forgive me if it's obvious): Why not `grep` your source code for any less-than signs that aren't followed by a space? AFAIK less-than signs are only used for less-than comparison and when specifying a generic type; nothing else. And AFAIK there's no way to actually use a generic without mentioning the full (closed) type name somewhere. Maybe you'll find some use of generics that way...

Comment: Also, while this most likely won't help you, I remember that when I was working with COM interop, I usually had to change the `CLSCompliant` and `ComVisible` attribute values because the compiler was complaining about the use of generics (COM cannot deal with generics). Maybe you could also abuse these flag attributes for your ends (though I don't think so to be honest).

Comment: @stakx: What about less-than signs in comments? strings? XML doc comments?  The << and <<= operators? What does there being a space have to do with it? "bool x = a<b;" is perfectly legal; there is no requirement that a less-than have a space after it.  Also, your contention that there is no way to use a generic without mentioning the type somewhere is incorrect. Consider "object x = C.X;" where C.X is a field of type IEnumerable<int>.  The program uses generics but does not have any generic syntax.

Comment: @Eric: **1.** Yes, no doubt you *will* get lots of false matches besides those that would be of interest. Nevertheless: it will still reduce the total number of lines of code you have to read through to a fraction; and second, that was just a suggestion; someone proficient with regexes would probably come up with a pattern that rules out even more "false positives". **2.** _"where C.X is a field of type IEnumerable<int>"_; that's fine, because C.X is declared or initialized somewhere and one needs to find these spots to catch the generic type. But the complete source code must be searched.

Comment: @Eric, that all being said, of course I realise that your solution with the compiler switch is the far better solution. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @stakx, even though we have already been over the code with "grep" on all sorts of Generics attributes there could be other ways to identify it. We will however try the compiler switch now :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there some way to turn off support for Generics in VS2010 so that the compiler will flag the offending line ?

Yes, but it is a "nuclear" option:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> x = null;
    }
}
```

---

```
C:\> csc /langversion:ISO-1 \foo.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\foo.cs(9,12): error CS1644: Feature 'generics' cannot be used because it is
        not part of the ISO-1 C# language specification
```

---

The ISO-1 switch turns off **all features that were not in C# 1.0**, which might be more features than you want to turn off.

Note that the switch is not intended to be a "emulate C# 1.0 in the C# 2.0 compiler" switch; if you want to run the C# 1.0 compiler, just run it. The switch is intended to identify features that were not present in the particular version and disallow them.

Note that the switch also possibly does not do everything you need it to do. All it does is disallow uses of generic *syntax*. If you are using a generic *type* without actually using generic *syntax*, the switch doesn't catch it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will communicate this to my partner and get back with the result - but this looks really promising!

Comment: Update: It wasn't the C# code that had any Generics "hidden" inside, it was the Eazfuscator.NET obfuscator that added a System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string> during obfusctating.

Answer (score 6):

There's no such *specific* compiler switch.

You can take a look at the source code (or the decompiled source) and search for usages of generics. Generics can be *declared* in your project or generic constructs (classes, methods, variables, ...) can be *used* by your project.

You might want to use reflection to look for generic declarations (classes, methods, fields, ..., but not variables) in your assembly. To look for usage of generics, you need to look into the IL instructions as well. A library like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) can help you with this.

**UPDATE**

Turns out (with Eric Lippert help, of course) you can compile your code for the C# 1.0 spec with this switch:

> [/langversion:ISO-1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4ckecs0.aspx)

Apart from generics, you'll also miss on *a few* things that were added to [C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cz8t42e(v=vs.80).aspx) and later.

**SAMPLE CODE**

With Mono.Cecil, you can load an assembly and get all its types:

```
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Rocks;

...

var asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("MyAssembly.dll");
var types = asm.MainModule.GetAllTypes();
```

And then start making interesting queries against them:

```
var genericTypes = types.Where(type => type.HasGenericParameters);

var genericMethods = types.
  Select(type => 
    type.Methods.Where(method => method.HasGenericParameters));

var genericFields = types.
  Select(type => 
    type.Fields.Where(field => field.DeclaringType.HasGenericParameters));

var genericMethodInstructions = types.Select(type =>
  type.Methods.Where(method => method.HasBody).
  Select(method => method.Body.Instructions.
    Where(instruction => instruction.Operand is MethodReference).
    Select(instruction => (MethodReference)instruction.Operand).
    Where(methodRef => methodRef.Resolve().HasGenericParameters)));
```

Comment: There most certainly is such a compiler switch.